# PHP: Different results with is_readable() between CLI and Apache

Tags: php, linux, file

When getting if a local file is readable with is_readable() function, I am obtaining different results when run from the browser than when running from command line.

Script using:

```
<?php
var_dump(php_ini_loaded_file());
var_dump(phpversion());
var_dump(posix_getuid());
var_dump(is_readable('/dev/shm/rrds'));
?>
```

I am checking same php.init file, phpversion and user, all equals and still getting false for is_readable() from browser and true from cli.

Browser output:

```
string(12) "/etc/php.ini" string(5) "5.3.3" int(48) bool(false)
```

CLI output

```
string(12) "/etc/php.ini"
string(5) "5.3.3"
int(48)
bool(true)
```

Permissions of /dev/shm/rrds: drwxr-xr-x.

/dev/shm is mounted as tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")

Does anyone know why?!

Comment: When executing with the browser, is_readable should return true as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was SELinux. I needed to disable it!

Answer (score 1):

Apache user is www-data. Cli user is the user from which the command is run.

To identify the user which run cli command

```
whoami
```

Run command from www-data

```
sudo -u www-data command
```

Comment: Since posix_getuid() is getting the same ID I am using the same user which is apache in my system.

Comment: posix_getuid — Return the real user ID of the current process. Your cli user is not www-data. If you run script by root user posix_getuid return uid of root user, not apache.

Comment: My apache server is configured with "User apache", so apache user is being used. In my system, www-data does not exist...

Comment: You right. Check your apache config, disable modules suexec, userdir and similar.

Comment: Also set open_basedir to "none" in apache config

Comment: Thanks guys! It was SELinux! (I was also checking open_basedir)